# Angular 2 ts-files to js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm going to use Angular 2 for my Spring frontend. 
Can someone explain please, how to compile all of ts-files to js-files and move all project carefully (with all dependencies) to view folder, which is located in WEB-INF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use something like:

```
module.exports = {
   output: {
     path: "..../WEB_INF/...",
     filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: "ts"
        }

 }
```

This worked for me (however we eventually separated the spring backend from the pure ts front-end)

Comment: this is using webpack take a look at this recent article i found https://github.com/edc4it/webpack-intro-tutorial

Comment: Jenny, and is there any decision, just to compile all of *.ts files to js, and after just launch, for example, index.html. Without any server, just with browser only?

Comment: that link indeed no longer works for me either. Their article is here http://www.edc4it.com/blog/web/webpack-tutorial.html (very basic, but explains it good)